# Implications of MobileConnect SMS Long Code

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

We have been provided a long code from Salesforce, as it appears to be needed for international messaging. From reading general websites regarding the pros/cons for short codes vs. long codes, there is one particular item I've seen posted that has me a bit worried:

> Finally, the messaging throughput with long codes is slower than a
>   sloth creeping down a tree for his afternoon snack. In fact, leading
>   providers can still only send 1 message per second on a long code.
>   That makes sending a messaging blast to a one million person database
>   an 11 day adventure.

Is it true that SMS messages sent with a long code will be that much slower than a short code, or is MobileConnect somehow able to bypass this limitation?

Source: https://uplandsoftware.com/mobile-messaging/resources/blog/long-codes-vs-short-codes-the-long-and-the-short-of-it/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Long Codes are meant for 1:1 meaningful conversations, not mass messaging. The 1 message per second restriction is correct.

What I would talk to SFMC about is looking to get a short code AND a long code. Use the short code for the bulk stuff in US, etc. and then Long Code for everyone else. This should help reduce the turn time for your SMS campaigns.

**Taken straight from [Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134587-Why-use-a-short-code-instead-of-a-long-code-):**

> Long codes are meant for **person-to-person communications, and can send
>   only 1 message per second**. For high-volume, application-driven
>   messaging, Twilio recommends using a short code. **Short codes can send
>   SMS and MMS at 100 messages per second**, and this high throughput is
>   perfect for applications needing to send time-sensitive messages to
>   many users at once. Furthermore, since carriers vet and approve all
>   short codes for their intended use, they are not subject to carrier
>   filtering or suspension for heavy traffic.

Other references:

https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2015/02/25/u-s-sms-long-codes-vs-short-codes-what-is-best-for-my-use-case/

https://blog.trumpia.com/sms-short-codes-vs.-sms-long-codes-what-you-need-to-know

Comment: Interesting. Person-to-Person isn't even viable with MobileConnect. Thanks for confirming